# Save password in "Add to Home Screen" shortcut on Safari on iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, safari

I have a password-protected admin site that uses HTTP basic auth to verify a username and password before serving the page.

Some clients want to add a shortcut to the web page on their iPhone's home screen by using the "Add to Home Screen" feature in Safari on iOS.

But every time I launch the web app from the shortcut, it prompts for the username and password.

Is it possible to save the username and password so they don't have to re-enter it every time the shortcut is launched?